# Align inline asm instruction

Tags: windows, visual-c++, alignment, inline, inline-assembly

I want to define slide of nop's or any other asm instruction in visual c++, i am pretty sure its possible using #define _emit align() ?
I want to define like 200 nops at once without having to do "#define __asm nop __asm nop __asm nop ...."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So do you want align or do you want a number of repeated instructions?

If you want align, you can get align:

```
__asm
{
    align 16
    nop
    align 16
    nop
    align 16
}
```

If you want to repeat instructions, you have to do it through defines.

```
#define NOP1 __asm nop
#define NOP4 NOP1 NOP1 NOP1 NOP1
#define NOP16 NOP4 NOP4 NOP4 NOP4 NOP4
#define NOP64 NOP16 NOP16 NOP16 NOP16
#define NOP256 NOP64 NOP64 NOP64 NOP64

int main()
{
  NOP256
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: There was other method using align and _emit but not sure how it was.

Comment: I think I understand what you're looking for. But I've never heard of this method, it's not documented in MSDN, and it does not show up easily in Google.